# How to set a timer with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am coding with an Arduino board the driving of a DC motor for a school project. With two push buttons to start / stop and also to change the direction of rotation. I also set a condition so that the motor stops when the current value given by my current sensor linked to the arduino board stops above a certain value.

My problem is that I don't want the first sensor current measurement (output Value) to be taken into account when the engine starts.

I tried to use a timer but being a beginner I failed to get the desired result. How could I code a timer which would ensure that when the motor starts, my condition (outputValue> = 0.3) is only effective after a few seconds after the first measurement of the current value?

```cpp
const int controlPin1=2;
const int controlPin2=3;
const int enablePin=9;
const int directionSwitchPin=4;
const int onOffSwitchStateSwitchPin=5;
const int potPin=A0;

int onOffSwitchState=0;
int previousOnOffSwitchState=0;
int directionSwitchState=0;
int previousDirectionSwitchState=0;

int motorEnabled=0;
int motorSpeed=0;
int motorDirection=1;

const int analogInPin = A1; // Analog input pin that the current sensor is attached to
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the sensor
float outputValue = 0;

void setup() { 
  pinMode(directionSwitchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(onOffSwitchStateSwitchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(controlPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(controlPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enablePin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin); // reads the sensor value and convert it
  outputValue = -(2.5 - (sensorValue * (5.0 / 1024.0)));

  onOffSwitchState = digitalRead(onOffSwitchStateSwitchPin);
  delay(1);
  directionSwitchState = digitalRead(directionSwitchPin);
  motorSpeed=analogRead(potPin) / 4;

  if  (onOffSwitchState != previousOnOffSwitchState) {
    if (onOffSwitchState == HIGH) {
      motorEnabled=!motorEnabled;
    }
  }

  if (directionSwitchState != previousDirectionSwitchState) {
    if (directionSwitchState == HIGH) {
      motorDirection=!motorDirection;
    }
  }

  if (motorDirection == 1) {
    digitalWrite(controlPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(controlPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(controlPin2, HIGH);
  }

  if (motorEnabled == 1) {
    analogWrite(enablePin, motorSpeed);
  } else {
    analogWrite(enablePin, 0);
  }

  if (outputValue >= 0.3) {
    digitalWrite(controlPin1, LOW);
    delay(5000);
  }

  previousDirectionSwitchState = directionSwitchState;
  previousOnOffSwitchState = onOffSwitchState;

  Serial.print("Current Sensor value= " ); // print results
  Serial.print(outputValue);      
  Serial.println("A");      
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you removed the code. It didn't make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first measurement store a timestamp like so:

```
unsigned long waitTime = 3000; // ms
unsigned long startTime = millis();
```

Make sure you're in the right scope.

then later, probably in a loop

```
if( millis() - startTime >= waitTime)
```

do your stuff

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try as soon as I can